# I am getting a 403 error: "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "ipRefererBlocked", in YouTube Data API v.3

Tags: youtube

I am getting a 403 error:

> "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "ipRefererBlocked", in YouTube Data API v.3

With the following call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLSnMNeASC5B5RBEBJClz6DdLEa-W9TM7t&key=AIzaSyAplIcFznd1OxBaMWM2LBN9uLBOVITMYxs

Also tried

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLSnMNeASC5B5RBEBJClz6DdLEa-W9TM7t&clientId=200447294473-i5a20md5sgpq20mai9ob2tiib8nqln9t.apps.googleusercontent.com

and getting this error:

> "domain": "usageLimits",
>       "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
>       "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
>
> ### "code": 403,
>
> API and credentials are authorized and within daily quota, intact, below 0.07/sec/day.

Could you please provide some assistance?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue while integrating to wordpress. Below listed are the fix/ mistakes I made, may help you.

1. ensure YouTube API is enabled
2. initially remove any domain restrictions from "Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)". later once its working u can add DOMAIN name
3. generate and use "browser" type key if integrating to website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change/set Browse key instead of android Key.

Also you need to checked the section **Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)** from Google Developers Console > API Manager > Credentials

Answer (score 0):

to accept all requests from your website(or domain) add this lines to **Website restrictions** area in google cloud api restriction screen

> Any subdomain or path URLs in a single domain, using wildcard asterisks (*):

```
*.example.com/*

http://*.example.com/*

https://*.example.com/*
```